# Selenium Python to Scrape a Website For Product and Color

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

here is the source for what i want to scrape

view-source:https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets

```
</div></div></li><li><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/jackets/g84fwstrv/tlxs5mzgi"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/189108/vi/2-yV7cMNF3Q.jpg" alt="2 yv7cmnf3q" /></a><div class="product-name"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g84fwstrv/tlxs5mzgi">Supreme®/Barbour® Lightweight<br> Waxed Cotton Field Jacket</a></div><div class="product-style"><a class="name-link" href="/shop/jackets/g84fwstrv/tlxs5mzgi">Orange</a>
```

for example i want my scraper to be able to find any product based on the keywords which here would be Supreme/Barbour Lightweight Waxed Cotton Field Jacket and then the colorway Orange. Note that is an example and that the url's for products are dynamic so i need to be able to get the text that i want everytime not just an xpath to click on that exact link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/web-scraping-tutorial-python/) that explains how I'm using `select` and CSS selectors.

#### CSS Selectors

These selectors are how the CSS language allows developers to specify HTML tags to style. Here are some examples:

`html body` — finds all body tags inside of an html tag.

`p.outer-text` — finds all p tags with a class of outer-text.

With CSS selectors in mind, you should inspect the webpage for useful information like tags (a, p, img) and identifiers (id, class). To specifically find the links, you find `div` tags with the class name `inner-article`, find `a` tags within it, and extract the `href`.

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/jackets")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

base_url = "https://www.supremenewyork.com"

names = soup.select('div.product-name')
styles = soup.select('div.product-style')
links = [base_url + x.find('a')["href"] for x in soup.select('div.inner-article')]

for name,style,link in zip(names, styles, links):
    print(f"Name: {name.text},  Style: {style.text}, Link: {link}")
```

Output:

```
Name: Supreme®/Barbour® Lightweight Waxed Cotton Field Jacket,  Style: Leopard, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/g84fwstrv/a9och5sqd
Name: Supreme®/Barbour® Lightweight Waxed Cotton Field Jacket,  Style: Orange, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/g84fwstrv/tlxs5mzgi
Name: Supreme®/Barbour® Lightweight Waxed Cotton Field Jacket,  Style: Black, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/g84fwstrv/uw3m41dl6
Name: Military Trench Coat,  Style: Olive Paisley, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/warmwnguk/vt4hfl7nb
Name: Military Trench Coat,  Style: Peach Paisley, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/warmwnguk/l42els7zp
Name: Military Trench Coat,  Style: Black, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/warmwnguk/agyucqie3
Name: Raglan Court Jacket,  Style: Black, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/df2mva4b6/z5rpqg4is
Name: Raglan Court Jacket,  Style: Flags, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/df2mva4b6/iise068yb
Name: Raglan Court Jacket,  Style: Pale Yellow, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/df2mva4b6/rfkb2ci4n
Name: Raglan Court Jacket,  Style: Olive, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/df2mva4b6/ovblpjzm6
Name: Twill Varsity Jacket,  Style: Light Blue, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/g0qtwiyl1/xbxlunom8
Name: Twill Varsity Jacket,  Style: Black, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/g0qtwiyl1/f1w9ue5vl
Name: Big Letter Track Jacket,  Style: Black, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/olcwsx6yg/dcpah7svl
Name: Big Letter Track Jacket,  Style: Dark Orange, Link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/jackets/olcwsx6yg/p5eiyuxlj
```

If you want to specifically look for name and style and get the link, take in user input and add a stop condition in the for loop.

(Also, I'm not 100% sure why someone downvoted the question, but I would suggest providing a clear description, goal, and attempted code. In the future, ask what type of tools to use for this project instead of asking for a full solution from SO)

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch im pretty new so i will note that but the code i have now navigates to supremes url for a certain product and from there i used x paths to fill out forms checkout etc.  Could you point me in the right direction if i want to find a product by keywords say Twill Varsity Jacket Style:black how would i accomplish this so it takes me to that products url where my code does everything else i need

Comment: I added more detail. Hopefully this leads to the solution. If this is good, please select this as an acceptable answer. Thanks.

Comment: really appreciate the help and thanks for the link to the tutorial